# sub arraylist's size isn't correct

Tags: java, arraylist

After hard searchig I still haven't found the proper answer for my question and there is it:

I have to write a java program that enters an array of strings and finds in it the largest sequence of equal elements. If several sequences have the same longest length, the program should print the leftmost of them. The input strings are given as a single line, separated by a space.

For example:

> if the input is: "hi yes yes yes bye",
>
> the output should be: "yes yes yes".

And there is my source code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a sequence of strings separated by spaces:");
    
    Scanner inputStringScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String[] strings = inputStringScanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    System.out.println(String.join(" ", strings));
    
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringsSequencesCollection = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> stringsSequences = new ArrayList<String>();
    stringsSequences.add(strings[0]);
    
      for (int i = 1; i < strings.length; i++) {
        if(strings[i].equals(strings[i - 1])) {
            stringsSequences.add(strings[i]);
        } else {
            
            System.out.println(stringsSequences + " " + stringsSequences.size());
            
            stringsSequencesCollection.add(stringsSequences);
            stringsSequences.clear();
            stringsSequences.add(strings[i]);
            
            //ystem.out.println("\n" + stringsSequences);
        }
        
        if(i == strings.length - 1) {
            stringsSequencesCollection.add(stringsSequences);
            stringsSequences.clear();
            
            System.out.println(stringsSequences + " " + stringsSequences.size());
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(stringsSequencesCollection.size());
    System.out.println(stringsSequencesCollection.get(2).size());
    System.out.println();
    
    int maximalStringSequence = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int index = 0;
    ArrayList<String> currentStringSequence = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < stringsSequencesCollection.size(); i++) {
        currentStringSequence = stringsSequencesCollection.get(i);
        
        System.out.println(stringsSequencesCollection.get(i).size());
        
        if (stringsSequencesCollection.get(i).size() > maximalStringSequence) {
            maximalStringSequence = stringsSequencesCollection.get(i).size();
            index = i;
            //System.out.println("\n" + index);
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(String.join(" ", stringsSequencesCollection.get(index)));
```

I think it should be work correct but there is a problem - the sub array list's count isn't correct: All the sub arrayList's size is 1 and for this reason the output is not correct. I don't understand what is the reason for this. If anybody can help me to fix the code I will be gratefull!

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by 'the sub array list's count isn't correct'? Or better, what do you mean by 'the sub array list'?

Put it another way: what is your input and what is your expected vs actual output?

Comment: My input is:
hi yes yes yes bye

Comment: And what is you expected output? And your actual output?

Comment: My input is:
hi yes yes yes bye

the output should be:
yes yes yes

I first record the input in the String[] strings variable. Then I decided to record the first element of "strings" in a arraylist variable - stringsSequences. Then the program iterates over the strings array and if it finds a string equal to the previous one it will add it to stringsSequences. Else the program will do the following:
1) add the stringSequences arrayList to a two dimensional arraList;
2) clear it;
3) add the current string to the empty stringSequences list.
Then the program should compare the size of arraLists

Comment: and take and print the array list with biggest size:

ArrayList<String> currentStringSequence = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < stringsSequencesCollection.size(); i++) {
        currentStringSequence = stringsSequencesCollection.get(i);

        System.out.println(stringsSequencesCollection.get(i).size());

        if (stringsSequencesCollection.get(i).size() > maximalStringSequence) {
            maximalStringSequence = stringsSequencesCollection.get(i).size();
            index = i;
            //System.out.println("\n" + index);
        }
    }

Comment: I don't understand why the size of all subarraylists in stringsSequencesCollection is 1? It consists of 3 subarraylists with following elements and corresponding size:
1) hi -> 1;
2) yes yes yes -> 3;
3) bye -> 1.
You see that the second subarraylist has size 3 and it should be printed in the output...

Comment: No, you are clearing them! See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fairly straight forward just keep track of a max sequence length as you go through the array building sequences.

```
String input = "hi yes yes yes bye";
String sa[] = input.split(" ");
int maxseqlen = 1;
String last_sample = sa[0];
String longest_seq = last_sample;
int seqlen = 1;
String seq = last_sample;
for (int i = 1; i < sa.length; i++) {
    String sample = sa[i];
    if (sample.equals(last_sample)) {
        seqlen++;
        seq += " " + sample;
        if (seqlen > maxseqlen) {
            longest_seq = seq;
            maxseqlen = seqlen;
        }
    } else {
        seqlen = 1;
        seq = sample;
    }
    last_sample = sample;
}
System.out.println("longest_seq = " + longest_seq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of issues.

First of all, when dealing with the last string of the list you are not actually printing it before clearing it. Should be:

```
if(i == strings.length - 1)
  //...
  System.out.println(stringsSequences + " " + stringsSequences.size());      
  stringsSequences.clear();
```

This is the error in the output.

Secondly, and most importantly, when you do stringsSequencesCollection.add you are adding an OBJECT, i.e. a reference to the collection. When after you do stringsSequences.clear(), you empty the collection you just added too (this is because it's not making a copy, but keeping a reference!). You can verify this by printing stringsSequencesCollection after the first loop finishes: it will contain 3 empty lists.

So how do we do this? First of all, we need a more appropriate data structure. We are going to use a Map that, for each string, contains the length of its longest sequence. Since we want to manage ties too, we'll also have another map that for each string stores the leftmost ending position of the longest sequence:

```
Map<String, Integer> lengths= new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Integer> indexes= new HashMap<>();
String[] split = input.split(" ");
lengths.put(split[0], 1);
indexes.put(split[0], 0);
int currentLength = 1;
int maxLength = 1;
for (int i = 1; i<split.length; i++) {
  String s = split[i];
  if (s.equals(split[i-1])) {
    currentLength++;
  }
  else {
    currentLength = 1;
  }

  int oldLength = lengths.getOrDefault(s, 0);
  if (currentLength > oldLength) {
    lengths.put(s, currentLength);
    indexes.put(s, i);
  }

  maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, currentLength);
}
//At this point, youll have in lengths a map from string -> maxSeqLengt, and in indexes a map from string -> indexes for the leftmost ending index of the longest sequence. Now we need to reason on those!
```

Now we can just scan for the strings with the longest sequences:

```
//Find all strings with equal maximal length sequences
Set<String> longestStrings = new HashSet<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e: lengths.entrySet()) {
  if (e.value == maxLength) { 
    longestStrings.add(e.key);
  } 
}

//Of those, search the one with minimal index
int minIndex = input.length();
String bestString = null;
for (String s: longestStrings) {
  int index = indexes.get(s);
  if (index < minIndex) {
    bestString = s;
  }
}
System.out.println(bestString);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer  - I found and fix my mistake now :)

Comment: @RosenPetrov if the answer satisfies you, please remember to tick it as correct to close the question

Answer (score 0):

Below code results in output as you expected:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a sequence of strings separated by spaces:");

        Scanner inputStringScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] strings = inputStringScanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        System.out.println(String.join(" ", strings));

        List <ArrayList<String>> stringsSequencesCollection = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        List <String> stringsSequences = new ArrayList<String>();
        //stringsSequences.add(strings[0]);
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 1; i < strings.length; i++) {
            if(strings[i].equals(strings[i - 1])) {
                if(flag == false){
                stringsSequences.add(strings[i]);
                flag= true; 
                }
                stringsSequences.add(strings[i]);
            }
        }

        int maximalStringSequence = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int index = 0;
        List <String> currentStringSequence = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < stringsSequencesCollection.size(); i++) {
            currentStringSequence = stringsSequencesCollection.get(i);

            System.out.println(stringsSequencesCollection.get(i).size());

            if (stringsSequencesCollection.get(i).size() > maximalStringSequence) {
                maximalStringSequence = stringsSequencesCollection.get(i).size();
                index = i;
                //System.out.println("\n" + index);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(stringsSequences.toString());
```